# too many threads by CachedThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following codes:

```
val executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4)

val futures = dataToProcess flatMap {
        case (name, dataByDate) =>
          dataByDate map {
            case (date, data) =>
              (name, date, data) -> executor.submit(new Callable[ProcessResult] {
                override def call() = {
                  val result = processor.process(...)
                  persist(result, name, date, data)
                  result
                }
              })
          }
      }
```

In `processor.process()`, some threadpools (**Executors.newFixedThreadPool(64)**) are used to process data. **These thread pools are not created on the fly**

In the above codes, we got about 100K following errors:

`...
Exception in thread "Thread-129359954" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Exception in thread "Thread-129359959" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Exception in thread "Thread-129359963" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Exception in thread "Thread-129359966" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Exception in thread "Thread-129359970" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Exception in thread "Thread-129359978" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
...`.

I have no idea why so many threads created. Any comments welcomed. Thanks.

UPDATE

I found that in the code base, which is a Java web application, in `contextInitialized()`, some thread pools (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`and `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`) are created and reused in many instances. **But `shutdown()` are not called explicitly in `contextDestroyed()`**. What will happen if these thread pools are not shutdown explicitly. I wonder whether it is the reason for so many threads.

Comment: Don't create thread pools and executors on the fly. Just have your processor use the same executor you create at the top level.

Comment: That number, 129362014, probably is not a serial number. Don't assume that it means your program has created more than one hundred million threads. The number most likely is derived from the virtual memory address of the Thread object.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your execution is done, thread is returned to the pool. Even if you shutdown, I assume you are still creating too many executor services in parallel. And the shutdown will wait for all the tasks to finish. So you will have resource contention.